# How to retrieve information about shown ads

Tags: google-chrome, firefox-addon, ads

I would like to retrieve information about shown ads on any website, like for example this website you're reading. I would like to retrieve information like

- Where does the ad come from (AdSense, DFP, etc)
- What is the targetted (destination) URL
- What is the path of redirects untill destination (if any)

Is there any software or extensions for Chrome or FireFox out there? I'm bassically looking for something does the opposite of the Chrome extension "AdBlocker Plus"

Answer (score 0):

you can either iterate over all frame objects, but this is not so accurate because what if an ad is in html

but then what if the add is in the html and they added it in the php.

i think your answer is to use observer service for http-on-modify-response

change http-on-examine-response to http-on-modify-response in this code here:

https://github.com/Noitidart/loadcontext-and-http-modify-observer

when you change to http-on-modify-response you will see every redirect. if you don't, and keep http-on-exmaine-response you will see just the final location of redirect

and you can watch every single thing that loads if it matches a list of ad url's then you know